# How can I install Ubuntu on an external hardrive from Windows?

Tags: external-hdd, system-installation

I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 on an external hard drive from Windows 7 itself so that I can do other things while it is installing. The tutorials I saw on Google tell me to first get it on a DVD and then install it on to the external HDD. Is it possible to do a direct install instead?

How can I install Ubuntu on an external hardrive from Windows?

Comment: Please clarify what you meant by installing Ubuntu from Windows. Wubi Installer?

Comment: @ErkinAlpGüney - Yakshemash. I mean, open windows, "install ubuntu" on to external hard drive, switch off pc, turn on and boot into ubuntu with external hard drive. Does it make a sense now ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't install it from windows. You have to boot it from a CD or USB drive (see http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) and then install it from there. As far as HOW to install it, boot it up from your install disk, then install it as normal until you get to the partition part, then click "something else", and change the device from your main hard drive to your external one. Make sure you've backed up your external hard drive if you have anything on it before you do any of this. Move/ format/ re size the necessary partitions and then just install. Just be careful you select the right disk and such when you do so because you risk losing your data on whatever drive you install it on.